# How to handle mime types, file extension and magic number on file upload, renaming and file download?

Tags: file-upload, file-types, mime-type

I am writing a simple server for file uploading. I want to be able to rename uploaded files (including the file extension) and download files.

For validating the file to upload my plan was to check if the mime type, the file extension and the magic number match. Only then the file will be uploaded to the server, assigned a UUID, stored on the server under its UUID. In the db I will store the file name, size and mime type.

Now, when a user renames a file which changes the file extension, the magic number of the actual file content does not change. So when the user then tries to download that file and upload it again, the upload will fail, because the magic number and the mime type/file extension dont match.

Isnt this an antipattern?
The feature of renaming a file and sometimes changing the file extension is something I really dont want to miss on my server, so just restricting renaming to the file name (and force the extension to stay the same) is not an option.

Another question also rises: should I update the mime type stored in the db to match the new file extension when a file is renamed?
If I dont do this and preserve the original mime type, the download request will have a Content-Type header that does not match the extension of the download file, which again seems like bad practice to me. However, if I update the mime type of the db, I will lose the information what the file actual says it contains.

How would you design this system?

I wont make this server public (for now) and even if I would, only authenticated users (only me) will be able to upload, rename and download stuff, so I dont need super bullet proof security checks. However I am wondering how this is handled in professional software (like onedrive) and would like to know how to properly build a decent line of defense against such attacks.

Thanks in advance for your insights

Comment: I don't understand what security problem you are trying to solve here. Based on *"The feature of renaming a file and sometimes changing the file extension is something I really dont want to miss on my server"* it looks like it is not about maintaining a consistency between extension, mime type and content - so what are you actually trying to achieve? *"... decent line of defense against such attacks"* - you don't describe any attacks, so it is not clear what you refer to here.

Comment: You need to be in complete control over that filename and extension.  You can allow users to "rename" the file, but you won't actually be renaming any file stored on the server... just the name it's served back to the user as. (the download's filename can be whatever you like)  As for allowing them to change the extension... do not allow that.  On upload you'd case/switch based on the extension given... you'll explicitly write the extension in the switch.  Any extension not matching a case is not stored.  All user-input should be validated.  You should additionally scan all incoming files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am trying to develop a strategy to deal with potentially dangerous files that pretend to be something they arent. This includes how to properly validating the uploaded file, but thinking it through the questions in my post arised.

Comment: @browsermator exactly, renaming a file doesnt actually change the way its stored as its stored by its randomly assigned UUID. However I am curious why you would not allow to change the file extension. To what security risks could this lead? Renaming a file doesnt actually change its content, only (if implemented) the Content-Type header of the download request and the file name of the download. Also, what do you mean by "You should additionally scan all incoming files". Would you actually search the actual contents of the file instead of its metadata? And what would you search for?

Comment: I suppose you could if you case/switched it again... but better to just require them to update/re-upload a file if they're going to do that.  That way it runs through your same set of upload validations again.  (some validations/scans may clean certain files based on extension... for instance removing DTDs from XML files.)  "Scan files" = scan for viruses.   As for your name using randomly assigned UUID, I'd just use the DB record's UID as a part of the name.  (since it's already there and guaranteed to be unique)

Comment: Also be very careful if you are reading meta-data.  That's another attack vector.  People will target certain libraries that parse the data.

Comment: @AzusDkk:  Uploading, downloading or renaming files are not any risk by themselves. The risk come from how these files are used by others, i.e. opening files in applications, executing files, including files into other files (local file inclusion) etc - none of this is done in what you describe. So it is still not clear what kind of threats you want to protect from, which also means that the necessary mitigations are not clear.